# Replace string value in regular expression with integer value in python

Tags: python, regex

In my python code, a user enters a mathematical expression. I want to replace the variables with integer values and calculate the result. I can user regular expression in python to replace the variables with integer values but I cant calculate the sum as the replaced string I get is of type string. I can do it in tcl. It has a built in expr command where I simply pass the string and it automatically converts it to mathematical expression and calculates the result. Is there a way to do the same in python?

Thank you

Comment: We can't work for you, try and come back with errors and doubts.

Comment: Could you possibly give us an expected input and expected output/method? That would at least give us something to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is `eval`.
for example:

```
a=3
b=4
s="(a*a+b*b)**.5"
eval(s)
```

But be warned it maybe an security risk.
You may better use SymPy
http://sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: Don't use `eval()` unless you really really know what you are doing, and even then, just don't. Instead use `ast.literal_eval()` which is safe from malicious input.

Comment: @qarma Whilst I agree `eval` is *often* a bad idea (and *definitely* is in this case), `literal_eval` won't work in this case.

Comment: The correct duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006626/how-to-calculate-expression-using-sympy-in-python

Comment: Sorry I did not include my code. My code looks like this:

Comment: list=[1.0, 3,45, 5.65] 
string="x**2+y**2+z**2
Now I want to replace x,y and z with the list[0], list[1] and list[2] and then calculate the result. In tcl I can do the replacement by using 'regsub' and then giving the result to 'expr' to calculate the value. 
Thanks Lee I can try eval